# Computation Doppler shift in ppm

Tags: frequency, satellite, uav

I am computing Doppler shift for different flying platforms and after my first presentation, it was suggested to revise in ppm.

I compute always in Hz and have never heard even about this unit until the day of the presentation.

What does the representation in ppm give me?

How to compute Doppler shift in ppm? Probably I can not just convert Hz to ppm, right?

Comment: do you know what "ppm" stands for?

Comment: Note that ppm is used with many other parameters such as temperature, mixture concentration, to name just a few.  It is not unique to Doppler shift.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, yes I do, "parts per million" or not?

Comment: So then how do you (OP) think you would convert the doppler shift in Hz to PPM?  Hint, you need to know the carrier frequency.

Comment: @SteveSh, I know the carrier frequency used for the calculation of the Doppler shift